# The windows.alert() command in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I was trying to make a Rickroll, and post it up on my website, but I was stumped very early I tried various methods on getting this to work but it wont... Could anyone spot my problem. I'm not great at javascript, and the other simaler question's solutions are too personal.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <title=You Got RickRolled>
  <script>
  windows.alert("We're no strangers to love");
  windows.alert("You know the rules and so do I");
  windows.alert("A full commitment's what I'm thinking of");
  windows.alert("You wouldn't get this from any other guy");
  windows.alert("I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling");
  windows.alert("Gotta make you understand");
  windows.alert("Never gonna give you up");
  windows.alert("Never gonna let you down");
  windows.alert("Never gonna run around and desert you");
  windows.alert("Never gonna make you cry");
  windows.alert("Never gonna say goodbye");
  windows.alert("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");
  windows.alert("We've known each other for so long");
  windows.alert("Your heart's been aching, but");
  windows.alert("You're too shy to say it");
  windows.alert("Inside, we both know what's been going on");
  windows.alert("We know the game and we're gonna play it");
  windows.alert("And if you ask me how I'm feeling");
  windows.alert("Don't tell me you're too blind to see");
  windows.alert("Never gonna give you up");
  windows.alert("Never gonna let you down");
  windows.alert("Never gonna run around and desert you");
  windows.alert("Never gonna make you cry");
  windows.alert("Never gonna say goodbye");
  windows.alert("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");
  windows.alert("Never gonna give you up");
  windows.alert("Never gonna let you down");
  windows.alert("Never gonna run around and desert you");
  windows.alert("Never gonna make you cry");
  windows.alert("Never gonna say goodbye");
  windows.alert("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");
  windows.alert("(Ooh, give you up)");
  windows.alert("(Ooh, give you up)");
  windows.alert("Never gonna give, never gonna give");
  windows.alert("(Give you up)");
  windows.alert("Never gonna give, never gonna give");
  windows.alert("(Give you up)");
  windows.alert("We've known each other for so long");
  windows.alert("Your heart's been aching, but");
  windows.alert("You're too shy to say it");
  windows.alert("Inside, we both know what's been going on");
  windows.alert("We know the game and we're gonna play it");
  windows.alert("I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling");
  windows.alert("Gotta make you understand");
  windows.alert("Never gonna give you up");
  windows.alert("Never gonna let you down");
  windows.alert("Never gonna run around and desert you");
  windows.alert("Never gonna make you cry");
  windows.alert("Never gonna say goodbye");
  windows.alert("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");
  windows.alert("Never gonna give you up");
  windows.alert("Never gonna let you down");
  windows.alert("Never gonna run around and desert you");
  windows.alert("Never gonna make you cry");
  windows.alert("Never gonna say goodbye");
  windows.alert("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");
  windows.alert("Never gonna give you up");
  windows.alert("Never gonna let you down");
  windows.alert("Never gonna run around and desert you");
  windows.alert("Never gonna make you cry");
  windows.alert("Never gonna say goodbye");
  windows.alert("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no `windows.alert()`, unless you created something like that?

Comment: Well you're missing the `head` and `body` tags.  And it's `window`, not `windows`.  And your title tag is very wrong.  That is not how you write a title tag.  This is:  `<title> my title</title>`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read How [do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make sure you will get appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

[3 bugs you have]

-1st `<title=You Got RickRolled>` should be `<title>You Got RickRolled</title>`

-2nd use `alert("We're no strangers to love");` or window.alert

-3rd make sure you have `<head>` and `<body>`

> ### `<head>`
>
> The HTML  element provides general information (metadata) about the document, including its title and links to its scripts and style sheets.
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head
>
> ### `<body>`
>
> The HTML  Element represents the content of an HTML document. There can be only one  element in a document.
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>You Got RickRolled</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    alert("We're no strangers to love");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a `<head>` and `<body>` tag
2. change `windows.alert()` to `window.alert()`

[Here it is in codepen](https://codepen.io/floresfxf/pen/dzabYK). Probably refrain from hitting 'run'. It works. I promise.

Answer (score 0):

A message box in `JavaScript` is

```
alert("Your text here");
```

Answer (score 0):

it's **window.alert()**, not windows

And you can even ignore the **window.**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <title>You Got RickRolled</title>
  <script>
  alert("We're no strangers to love");
  alert("You know the rules and so do I");
  alert("A full commitment's what I'm thinking of");
  alert("You wouldn't get this from any other guy");
  alert("I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling");
  alert("Gotta make you understand");
  alert("Never gonna give you up");
  alert("Never gonna let you down");
  alert("Never gonna run around and desert you");
  alert("Never gonna make you cry");
  alert("Never gonna say goodbye");
  alert("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");
  alert("We've known each other for so long");
  alert("Your heart's been aching, but");
  alert("You're too shy to say it");
  alert("Inside, we both know what's been going on");
  alert("We know the game and we're gonna play it");
  alert("And if you ask me how I'm feeling");
  alert("Don't tell me you're too blind to see");
  alert("Never gonna give you up");
  alert("Never gonna let you down");
  alert("Never gonna run around and desert you");
  alert("Never gonna make you cry");
  alert("Never gonna say goodbye");
  alert("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");
  alert("Never gonna give you up");
  alert("Never gonna let you down");
  alert("Never gonna run around and desert you");
  alert("Never gonna make you cry");
  alert("Never gonna say goodbye");
  alert("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");
  alert("(Ooh, give you up)");
  alert("(Ooh, give you up)");
  alert("Never gonna give, never gonna give");
  alert("(Give you up)");
  alert("Never gonna give, never gonna give");
  alert("(Give you up)");
  alert("We've known each other for so long");
  alert("Your heart's been aching, but");
  alert("You're too shy to say it");
  alert("Inside, we both know what's been going on");
  alert("We know the game and we're gonna play it");
  alert("I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling");
  alert("Gotta make you understand");
  alert("Never gonna give you up");
  alert("Never gonna let you down");
  alert("Never gonna run around and desert you");
  alert("Never gonna make you cry");
  alert("Never gonna say goodbye");
  alert("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");
  alert("Never gonna give you up");
  alert("Never gonna let you down");
  alert("Never gonna run around and desert you");
  alert("Never gonna make you cry");
  alert("Never gonna say goodbye");
  alert("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");
  alert("Never gonna give you up");
  alert("Never gonna let you down");
  alert("Never gonna run around and desert you");
  alert("Never gonna make you cry");
  alert("Never gonna say goodbye");
  alert("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert('Never gonna give you up');
```

Instead of:

```
windows.alert('never gonna let you down');
```

Windows is not a thing.

```
window.alert('never gonna run around');
```

Would have also worked.

Answer (score -1):

There's a couple of other markup changes I would make as well:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <!-- Put the <title> tag within a '<head>' tag -->
      <title>You Got RickRolled></title>
    </head>
<!-- You want a body tag inside your <html> tags -->
    <body>
      <script>
      alert("We're no strangers to love");
      /* Rest of lyrics here */
      </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```